# how do you connect an ajax post to a specific conditional in PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So i have written a function that is called onclick in my html file that uses AJAX, but i would like for this post to go to a specific table in mysql.

```
   $('#submitIFC').click(function(e) {

 var request;

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
   var opinionIFC = $('ul.sort').sortable('toArray').join(',');

request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if ((request.readyState===4) &&(request.status===200))  {

     var return_data = request.responseText;
     document.getElementById('rank_ul').innerHTML= 'return_data';


    // Preventing the default action triggered by clicking on the link
    e.preventDefault();


    e.preventDefault();
    }//end of if
    }//end of onreadystatechange function    


//send requested movie to php file which will send to the external server
request.open("POST", "results.php", true);
request.send(opinionIFC);

document.getElementById('rank_ul').innerHTML='<img src="ajax-loader.gif">';
```

});

however there seems to be an issue with connecting this to my php if conditional, i tried copying the contents on my request.send(), like so

```
   if($_POST['opinionIFC'])
 {echo 
// The data arrives as a comma-separated string,
// so we extract each post ids:
$data=explode(',',str_replace('li','',$_POST['sortdata']));

// Getting the number of objects
list($tot_objects) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sort_objects"));

if(count($data)!=$tot_objects) die("Wrong data!");

foreach($data as $k=>$v)
{
    // Building the sql query:
    $str[]='('.(int)$v.','.($tot_objects-$k).')';
}

$str = 'VALUES'.join(',',$str);

// This will limit voting to once a day per IP:
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO `sort_votes` (ip,date_submit,dt_submit)
                VALUES ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',NOW(),NOW())");

//  If the user has not voted before today:
if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
{
    mysql_query('   INSERT INTO `sort_objects` (id,votes) '.$str.'
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE votes = votes+VALUES(votes)');
}
```

}

why isnt the ajax post request filtering through to my php file?

thank you so much, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you're using jquery, **WHY** are you rolling your own ajax code? all of that readystate junk can be replacec with a single `$.ajax()`. And your php code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending opinionIFC parameter, try:

```
request.send('opinionIFC=' + opinionIFC);
```

You also need to set Content-type

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```